# Numpy find agreement between columns in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have labels from 'n' different people who rated 'm' items (either 0 or 1), so an m x n array. For example, 3 people rating 4 items:

```
arr = np.asarray([[1,1,1], [1,1,0], [0,0,0], [0, 1, 0]])
print(arr)
>>>
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 1 0]]
```

I want to see on which items everyone "agreed", i.e. all values in the row are the same. In this example the answer is [True, False, True, False]. I got it working using this:

```
np.logical_or(arr.sum(axis=1) == n, arr.sum(axis=1) == 0)
```

Kind of hacky. What's a better way of doing this?

Comment: arr.sum(axis=1) % n == 0 also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would be to calculate the `diff` along the rows and then check whether all the `diff`s are equal to 0; This will make sure all elements in a row are the same (and can be different from 0 and 1):

```
(np.diff(arr, axis=1) == 0).all(axis=1)
# array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Or if you have only 0s and 1s, then:

```
(arr == 1).all(1) | (arr == 0).all(1)
# array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

arr.all(1) | ~arr.any(1)
# array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `len(set(.))` is basically the `is_uniform` function that you are looking for:

```
[len(set(x)) == 1 for x in arr]
```

Note that this solution is very general, it does not require:

1. the same number of people voted on each item
2. values to be numeric or any particular type
3. additional package on top of core python

Comment: This is slick. If arr was a list of lists (one list of ratings per each user), how would you modify this to make it work? You couldn't iterate through the rows as you do through the numpy array right now.

Comment: As my modified answer mentioned, this solution is not only slick, it is also very general:) Does this answer your follow up question?

Comment: Your solution assumes that arr is an iterable, and each object is a collection of <=n scores from various users. However, if arr was a collection of n lists/arrays each of length m, your solution will not work as-is. You'd have to reshape it somehow, and without numpy I don't immediately see an elegant way to do that - that was what I was asking.

Comment: Hmm, can you make an example and update your question? Hard to imagine arr not to be an iterable given the essence of the question, and whether <=n or not, I don't think it matters.

Comment: I think I figured it out: in that case you'd have to use zip() to make each respective row in the n lists into 1 tuple,  and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Or use `list comprehension` making elements that there length equals to the count of the first element of `i` (so basically see if they are all the same value in `i`), if they don't match with the condition, make them `False` instead:

```
print([len(i)==i.tolist().count(i[0]) for i in arr])
```

Output:

```
[True, False, True, False]
```